# How do I format this second to last formula? The "monthlyPayment"? Continuing to get a compiler error

Tags: c

Cannot figure out what is wrong with the formula for the monthlyPayment, I am brand new to programming and so far I have spent 6 hours on this program.

```
 void calcStuff(float loan, float rate, int years, float* monthlyPayment,     
 float* interestEarned)
 {
    //Define Variables
    float ratePer;
    int numPer;
    float a;
    float b;
    float powf( float a , float b );

    //Calculate the rate per period and number of periods
    ratePer = ( rate / 100 ) / 12;
    numPer = years * 12;
    a = ( 1 + ratePer );
    b = ( -numPer );

    //Calculate the monthly payments and the interest earned
    *monthlyPayment = (( ratePer * loan ) / ( 1 - powf ));
    *interestEarned = (( *monthlyPayment * numPer )-loan );

    return;
 }
```

I also cannot seem to format it correctly

Comment: Can you tell us what the compiler error is? It'll make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: `powf` is declared as a function taking two float arguments and returning a float, so `1 - powf` is meaningless ;)

Comment: @NiBZ Moreover that function is prototyped locally and never implemented.

Comment: invalid operands to binary - (have int and float (*)(float,  float))

Comment: You don't need to define powf there.  Just do a #include <math.h>, and then you can call it as powf(a, b);

Comment: So how would I need to declare it to make  1 - powf mean something? I'm sorry if these are dumb questions but this stuff is like a foreign language to me at times.

Comment: incluuding <math.h> will declare powf for you.  Instead if saying (1- powf), you would say (1 - pwf(a, b)).  That will call the powf function with the two parameters a and b, and return the result of raising a to the b power.  So, if a was 2.0 and b was 3.0 powf(a, b) would return 8.0.  Then (1 - 8.0) would be -7.0.  Not sure if that's what you want though.

Comment: Welcome  to StackOverflow. Let's get you started correctly here. When you have a problem, clearly describe that problem. *get a compiler error* is meaningless unless you also include what that error is - you have it right in front of you on your screen, and there is zero excuse for not including it in your question. You're asking for free help to solve your problem; the very least you can do is provide us with the information you already have available and clearly explain the problem, and ask a **specific** question. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You error probably comes from the `powf`, as mentionned in my comment. You can remove the declaration, it is not needed.

Also your `a` and `b` variables are never used. If you intended to divide by `(1 - a^b)` for your `monthlyPayment` formula, you can do it by using the actual `powf()` function, declared in `math.h` :

```
#include<math.h>
// your code
*monthlyPayment = (( ratePer * loan ) / ( 1 - powf(a, b) ));
```

Oh, and don't forget to link with `-lm` to use the libmath ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are awesome! So quick, saved me hours of getting nowhere.

Answer (score -1):

Not that its wrong, but why use pointer arguments here?

```
 void calcStuff(float loan, float rate, int years, float* monthlyPayment,     
     float* interestEarned)
```

Now, here:

```
//Define Variables
float ratePer;
int numPer;
float a;
float b;
float powf( float a , float b );
```

You are NOT DEFINING variables! You are DECLARING variables and you are also declaring a function. This difference is important in C. As far as variables are concern, this means that you're only declaring a name but you don't initialise memory with some value. In the case of the function it means that you're only declaring the signature of the function without actually defining what it should do. In C, too, you can't define a function within another function so declaring one with `float powf( float a , float b )` is an error and I'd expect your compiler to complain.

```
*monthlyPayment = (( ratePer * loan ) / ( 1 - powf ));
```

`( 1 - powf )` is an error of course. If you needed to call a function with powf's signature you should do it like this `powf(aFloat, anotherFloat)`. But as already mentioned there is no DEFINITION for such a function in your program, just a declaration and in a place where it shouldn't be. When parsed by your compiler, however, `powf` will probably trigger a "variable not declared" error of some sort since it looks like a variable which is not declared/defined anywhere in your code.

```
return;
```

Finally, there's no need to return anything.. your function is void.

Comment: The pointers are to allow the function to send back the calculated values to the caller, hence they are required here to get both `monthlyPayment` and `interestEarned`.

Comment: And by the way, an undefined function will not trigger any error at compile time (the declaration is enough for the compiler), but will trigger an error at link time, as the linker won't be able to actually find the function definition. In his case, the error is basically a type error (trying to subtract a function from an integer ... which is an error)

Comment: I'd considered it cleaner to simply those values (maybe using two separate functions) or at the very lease change the name of your function to something like `update_monthly_payment_and_interest` so that it's explicit to everyone reading the code that you're changing the values the pointers point to..